# Adjusting SQL 2012 and/or Office 2010 seed used by date functions

Tags: sql-server

We are doing some automation work with SQL 2012 and MS Office 2010.

We've imported some dates into a SQL table from Excel. In Excel, the dates appear in a readable format (e.g., 1st March 1989). We want to store the dates in SQL Server as integers.  For example, the underlying value for 1st March 1989 is 32568 in Office 2010: CLng(DateValue("01/03/1989")) using Australian date format.

The import of the Excel date into the SQL int column seemed to work.  However, when we checked, we found a discrepancy.  For example, 1st March 1989 appears as 32566 in SQL Server, not 32568.

We think we know how to fix the issue.  Our question is, does anyone know if the seed used by the date functions in Office 2010 and/or SQL 2012 can be adjusted and, if so, how?

Comment: *We want to store the dates in SQL Server as integers* Why?

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses `1900-Jan-0` as its begin date and SQL Server uses `1900-Jan-1`

> [Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214094): In this system, the serial number **1** represents 1/1/1900 12:00:00 a.m

But in SQL **1** is [Jan 2nd](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2708):

```
select cast(1 as datetime)
```

That's one diff. The second diff is the well know [Feb. 29th 1900 bug in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214058):

> in this date system, the year 1900 is incorrectly interpreted as a leap year.

All in all more reasons to store dates as dates, not as ints.

Comment: Thanks, Remus.  Perhaps I should have clarified that by "Excel" we meant "Excel VBA".  Our testing indicates the earliest date Excel 2010 can store is 30th November 100 (i.e., DateSerial(-1899,0,0)). The earliest date SQL 2012 can store is actually 1st January 1, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx.

Comment: To amplify: The earliest date Excel 2010 can store is 30th November 100 (i.e., DateSerial(-1899,0,0)). The earliest date SQL 2012 can store is 1st January 1 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).  To the best of our knowledge, all DBMS systems store dates as integers (or, for datetime data, as the integer portion of a float).  We could simply use an offset of 2 to get an exact match between Excel 2010 and SQL 2012, but we're curious to discover if their seed values can be adjusted.

Comment: This doesn't change anything. The problem is exactly as I stated, the int value '1' interpreted as a date has a different meaning in Excel (and VBA, of course, which just wraps the Excel features) compared to SQL.

Comment: And DBMS do no store dates as integers. They store dates as dates, a type with specific semantic: for example it can be passed to `DATEADD()` function, and the client libraries know how to present it as the appropriate type (eg. C# DateTime). The fact that the on-disk representation is a bag of bytes that can be interpreted like this or like that is irrelevant and definitely not your concern. I had to rescue projects that made the same bad decision you're making now countless times.